# Why in shouldComponentUpdate() nextProps and this.props are the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React app which has two form components.

I read that by default React re-renders all components when any state changes.

To improve performance I'd like to stop from re-rendering form 2 when user changes form 1 and vice-versa.

When I return false in shouldComponentUpdate it stops rendering that component and that is right however when I add logical comparisons to figure out whether current props state is different from nextProps state it gives me always the same result.

Here is an example https://glitch.com/edit/#!/smoggy-emmental-jep3kk5ly?path=src/App.js:8:17

If you open browser console it logs current props and nextProps also indicates which component is re-rendering.

Can you tell me what should I do to stop re-rendering form 2 when the user changes inputs in form 1?

Or what I am doing incorrectly?

I searched a lot but cannot find a helpful result.

Comment: @robinvrd Well, it does not say that shouldUpdateComponent is unsafe. ComponentWillUpdate is marked as unsafe.

Comment: My bad, I delete that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.js, all the methods(may it be this.nameChange or this.typeChange) are  changing the values on the same state.form object. Since it is the same instance of form object all the time, in shouldComponentUpdate of Form component `this.props.form == nextProps.from` is true.

If you want the props to change, instead of

```
let {form} = this.state;
form.type = e.target.value;
this.setState({form});
```

try doing

```
this.setState({ form: {...this.state.form, type: e.target.value} })
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. Thanks a lot. You saved me. So the main problem here was that I am using nested objects. If I used `this.state={formName:'foo'}` and changed that state normally `this.setState({formName:'something'})`  then shouldComponentUpdate would detect changes right?

Comment: Yes, shouldComponentUpdate would detect the changes of primitive types easily.

Comment: I got another problem while working with Map type. I have `this.state.form.files: new Map()` where images are stored. When I'm trying to remove an image and update files using setState current `props.form.files` and `nextProp.form.files` size is the same and I am not able to detect changes to re-render that component :/. I believe it is related to *Map* somehow, do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: If you are manipulating the same Map object instance, then yes, `props.form.files` and `nextProp.form.files` size would be same. So try cloning from the old map like this `newMap = new Map(oldMap)` and do the changes on the newMap and set it to state.

Comment: Oh yes, that worked. I was removing element first and then cloning it as new var. So that was a mistake. Thanks a lot.